# Como ordeno dias de la semana en el index de un dataframe en python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo un problema al leer con pandas un archivo .csv asigno una columna como index pero no puedo ordenarla de Lunes-Domingo, he intentado con librerías de tiempo y cambiar el formato de str a date, pero nada.

```
import pandas as pd

dataset_vc = pd.read_csv("videoconferencia.csv")
dataset_vc.head()

datavc = dataset_vc.pivot(index='Día', columns='Semana', values='Horas')
datavc
```

[image: Imagen from Jupyter]

Gracias, y perdón si la forma en que genero la consulta no es la correcta, saludos.

Comment: Deberias colocar el codigo donde haces dicho trabajo para que puedan corregirtelo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya que no proporcionas un csv con datos de prueba, crearé uno a base de repetir los mismos números (aleatorios) para tres semanas:

```
Semana,Día,Horas
Semana 01,Lunes,21983
Semana 01,Martes,38847
Semana 01,Miércoles,457849
Semana 01,Jueves,384245
Semana 01,Viernes,428789
Semana 01,Sábado,8329849
Semana 01,Domingo,446234
Semana 02,Lunes,21983
Semana 02,Martes,38847
Semana 02,Miércoles,457849
Semana 02,Jueves,384245
Semana 02,Viernes,428789
Semana 02,Sábado,8329849
Semana 02,Domingo,446234
Semana 03,Lunes,21983
Semana 03,Martes,38847
Semana 03,Miércoles,457849
Semana 03,Jueves,384245
Semana 03,Viernes,428789
Semana 03,Sábado,8329849
Semana 03,Domingo,446234
```

El truco es, tras leer este csv, hacer que la columna `Día` sea de tipo "categorical", en lugar de la cadena que es ahora mismo. El tipo de datos "categorical" permite especificar el orden interno de las categorías, además de ser más eficiente en memoria cuando se tienen unas pocas categorías (7 en este caso, una por día) repetidas muchas veces en una columna.

Se hace así:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("videoconferencia.csv")
dias_ordenados = ["Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado", "Domingo"]

df.Día = pd.Categorical(df.Día, dias_ordenados)
```

Con eso, el resto de tu código ya funciona como querías:

```py
datavc = df.pivot(index='Día', columns='Semana', values='Horas')
datavc
```

[image: resultado]